# Getting system time milliseconds

Tags: milliseconds, vb5

I am not a VB programmer, let alone a VB3 programmer on a Windows NT.
Everything here is difficult and ackward.

All what I have to do is to get system milliseconds.
So from [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?132229-Display-Time-in-millisecond)I know that this might be possible.

I therefore added the line:

> TimeValue=Gettickcount()

but that function is unknown. So I added (in another part of the code)

```
 Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

and that apparently works for it compiles. Except for the fact that at the runtime it says:
Kernel32 not found

So  I change and write Kernel32 **.dll** but now it doesn't find the dll
I search the dll on the system, I find it (367kb in C:\WinNt\System32\ ) and copy where the .mak resides but now it shows an

> Error in loading dll

Now I really don't know what else to do!

Please note that it is VB3 not VB5 as I wrote in the tag. There just wasn't a VB3 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6441
I get the solution for VB5-VB6.

Well almost the solution for it shows 1/100 of seconds not really 1/1000 but that is nearly there.

```
Public Function MyTime() As String
    MyTime = Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:nn:ss") & "." & Right(Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
End Function
```

It should work also on VB3. Give it a try!

Comment: Yep corrected now. Apologies. Credits to Brian M. Matumbura